# Flutter - ListView Animation - Increse size of item that is most visible / focused?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

Yeah, basically the title says it all. I want to see which item is most focused and then increase it size. This is the code I wrote but it has some huge problems with performance:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:tastie/models/HomeFeed.dart';
import 'package:tastie/models/Restaurant.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';
import 'restaurant_preview.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Home(this.feed);
  final HomeFeed feed;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double visible = 0;
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        for (Restaurant resto in feed.recents)
          (_restoprev(context, resto, visible)),
      ],
    );
  }
  Widget _restoprev(BuildContext context, Restaurant resto, double visible) {
    GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
    RestaurantPreview restopreview = RestaurantPreview(context, resto, key: _key);
    return Center(
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: VisibilityDetector(
          key: Key(resto.id + Random().nextInt(10000).toString()),
          onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
            if (info.visibleFraction > visible) {
              final RestaurantPreviewState previewState = _key.currentState;
              previewState.update(true);
            } else {
              final RestaurantPreviewState previewState = _key.currentState;
              previewState.update(true);
            }
          },
          child: restopreview,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But this code does not work because it is the opposite of smooth it lags behind and multiple widgets are effected. So my question is how to detect which view is most in focus and how to expand it? And is there another way to change the state of the restaurant because I read that GlobalKey is only used for debugging. Maybe use ObjectKey?

Answer (score 0):

There is Hero widget that does exactly what you're looking for.

Follow the flutter docs here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question will be long, fortunately there is a video that describe how to play with ListView controller.
the video is long but I recommenced you to watch it all, However the part you interested at begin after 9 min.
here the link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn6VCTaHB-k&t=326s